# Google maps does not work after resigning an apk

Tags: android, google-maps, decompiler, android-signing

I am doing some modification in an  existing apk that i got from my client to modify. I have decompiled application using apktool, changed some resources (like some strings from `strings.xml`) and recompiled/built it again using same tool. Then I signed using one_click_signer tool that I found somewhere of the google.

But when I install it on my device then google maps does not work anymore as it was working with original apk on the same device.

I have searched a lot about this but did not  got any solution.
I reviewed [this link](http://androidcracking.blogspot.in/2011/01/why-wont-google-maps-work-after.html) and many more and come to conclusion that I need to sign the apk with same key that was in original apk.

So can anyone please tell me:

1. how can I sign the apk again with the same key and make map work?
2. or is there any other  way to make maps work properly?

---

Solution That I found and worked for me:

Thanx for 
@apmartin1991's answer  . .

I created a   google api console project and got got the generated key.
then I replaced that key in **android-manifest.xml** file and resigned the application.

It worked.

Comment: why don't u have access to the source code ?

Comment: The "same key" means the private key from Google - hence forget it. If you want to use Google Maps use the Google maps API in your own app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to contact your client to get the .keystore file so you can sign it with the same key OR you can sign it with your own key and allow your key to be used with google maps, You can do this from the Google API console.

However if your clients app is on the appstore and you want to update that you MUST use the same key or it will be impossible to update it.

Answer (score 1):

You need .keystore file to use the same key. If you dont have .keystore file you need to generate a new one and register a new key in google maps console.

You have all the official instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key).