# Recompiling APK with Google Fit API Issues

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, moto-360

I'm attempting to reverse engineer an android app called HeartTrace in order to pull sensor data at a higher frequency. I decompiled, adjusted the parameters, and recompiled the APK. However, the app no longer connects to Google Fit API. Does the API require a new signature from Google before recompiling? If not, what is the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html),

> Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed.

Therefore, you need to digitally sign the app again using these two options:

- use the same key which can be found in `.keystore` file if the app has already been published in apps store, or
- generate a new key to be used in signing in

However, if you opt to use a new key, don't forget to check [Signing Considerations](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#considerations).

I highly recommend going through the given documentation wherein these are being discussed in complete details:

- describes how to sign your APKs, including creating and storing your certificate,
- signing different build configurations using different certificates, and
- configuring the build process to sign your APKs automatically.

And for additional information, this tutorial on [Google Fit for Android: Reading Sensor Data](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-reading-sensor-data--cms-25723) and solution given in this SO post - [Google maps does not work after resigning an apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492881/google-maps-does-not-work-after-resigning-an-apk) which is related to decompiling an Android app might also help.

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you so much! I did sign the app, but didn't resign the Google Fit API. So, what is the best way to recompile and still have the Google Fit API working? Thanks!